# Fedora - which proxy server?

Tags: proxy, proxy-server

Is there some **universal proxy server** for fedora linux which allows **any port**?

I know:

- **SQUID proxy** - seems that allows only HTTP and HTTPS (i'm using it now)
- **tiny proxy** - also HTTP and HTTPS only

I need to open FTP, and some other specific ports..

Answer (score 1):

squid allows HTTP "CONNECT" proxying, which is *usually* used for HTTPS but in reality can be used for any kind of TCP connections.

If you are setting up a simple personal proxy, you might be fine with the SOCKS 5 server built into all SSH clients: `ssh -D 1080 myhost` and you get a proxy on localhost:1080.

Both will work for passive-mode TCP (not active).

Comment: Thanks! Are you talking about these lines in SQUID.conf? `acl SSL_ports port 443 20 21`, `acl CONNECT method CONNECT` and `http_access deny CONNECT !SSL_ports`. It doesn't work.. So I'll try SOCK 5. And what is difference between passive and active mode?

Comment: @gaffcz: FTP is different from other popular protocols in that it uses "data" connections separate from the "control" connection. In active mode, the server will *connect back* to your client for a data transfer. In passive mode, the client initiates all connections. FTP active mode, as well as incoming connections of *any* kind, are complicated when behind NATs and almost impossible behind proxy servers. **Note:** In both modes, data connections use *randomly chosen* target port numbers, so you will likely have to allow *all* ports.